# Sharepoint 2010 Foundation: Workflow to set up repeating Audit Tasks and reminders

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation

Novice to Sharepoint. Looking for some advice regarding Workflows. I'm running Sharepoint 2010 **Foundation**. I've been asked to design an Audit Document Workflow. The Manager will create factory standard operating procedures docs and upload to a Library, then he will assign various people to audit and and edit if necessary. The process will repeat on a 6 monthly basis or kicked off manually or if the Document changes. Each task will be emailed to the chosen end user and reminders sent at specified intervals until the task is marked complete, then the process will automatically start again in 6 months time..

Is this possible in Foundation? Any advice, links or tips would be greatly apreciated.

PS I'm using Foundation for a reason - we have no budget! So no 3rd Party Apps or upgrades will be possible.

thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Are you using Sharepoint Designer or Visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following links for more information on workflow design and construction:

[msdn Reference on workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414204.aspx)

[technet workflow description](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff819861.aspx)

Good luck and I hope I could answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I was looking to get my hands on a few examples relating to Foundation because a lot of these articles only make reference to inbuilt Workflow functions that come out of the box for SP Server. Are there any specific examples of Workflows (either in written or video tutorial format) that start using a blank workflow template?